# Jquery function doesen't work when I change page/row or when I search some specific

Tags: php, jquery, json, database, datatable

I made a JQuery function the one deletes the row I selected. I know that the option exist in the DataTables option, but I want to do by myself, because I prefer to not use AJAX, just JQuery and JSON.
The problem appears when I search some specify row in the datatable with the search option, then I click the button to delete, and nothing happens. The other mistake is when I click to the next page, then, all the rows from that page will not work either.

Do you guys know what this could be?

Here I let my JQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {       

$( ".botFactura" ).click(function(e) {
    alert("jkn");
    idFact = this.id;
    var confirmacio = confirm("Segur que vol esborrar la factura "+idFact);
    /*if(confirmacio){
        $.post("operacions/borraFact.php", {idFact: idFact}, null, "json").done(function(data){
            alert(data.missatge);
        })
    }*/
});});
```

Then, I have the JSON file there:

```
<?php

 include("../connexio.php");
 $idFact= $_POST['idFact'];
 $arrayDatos = array();

  if($idFact!=""){
     $borrar = 'DELETE FROM factures WHERE id="'.$idFact.'"';
    //$connBorr = mysqli_query($conn,$borrar);

    $arrayDatos['missatge'] = "Factura ".$idFact." esborrada!";
    }else{
    $arrayDatos['missatge'] = "No s'ha trobat";
  }

  echo json_encode($arrayDatos);
  ?>
```

I call the $(".botFactura") there:

```
<button type="button" name="<?php echo $line2['id']?>" id="<?php echo line2['id']?>" class="btn btn-danger botFactura">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
</button>   
<button type="button" name="<?php echo $line2['id']?>" id="<?php echo $line2['id']?>" class="btn btn-success botFactura">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
  </button>
```

Finally, I'll upload some graphical example about what's my problem: 
:[The first one, is when the page works correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWxNn.png)

Then,the first issue appears when: [I change the page of the table. As we can see, I click and nothing happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccKa7.png)

The same issue appears when I try to search some specific row into the search box.

Well, I would really appreciate if someone could help to explain why this is not working! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which version of jQuery you are using but if you are jQuery 1.9 or upper version try this

```
$( document ).on('click', '.botFactura', function(e)
```

or if you are using lower version try this

```
$( ".botFactura" ).live('click', function(e)
```

Comment: Hi aman, Sorry for not put the version i'm using it, my header is that one: `<script src ="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />`

Comment: Replace your function line    $( ".botFactura" ).click(function(e)    with my first code